# Парсер данных из файла

Tags: логика, php, синтаксический-анализ, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как корректно реализовать парсер данных.
Описание:
 Имею длинный список, все данные из этого списка удаляются раз в месяц, так что довольно длинный получается. Ранее толком персерами не занимался, интересует логика сего. В данный момент:(в каждой строчке списка указано id время кол-во имя)

```
Открываем файл. 
 Создаю подключения с БД.
  цикл{
   выбираю строку
   проверяю не пуста ли она
    запрашиваю из таблицы данные(обычный select сравниваю по id и времени)
     если запись в базе присутствует, переходим к следующей строке
      если нет, то заносим в базу данных данные из строки.
    }
    закрыли подключение.
    закрыли файл.
```

Меня пугает получившееся в итоге куча mysql запросов... Что скажете по этому поводу?

Comment: Я бы создал вторую таблицу с нужными индексами (таблицу с тем, что должно быть вставлено). И на стороне бд сделал Update первой таблицы беря данные из второй и проверя есть ли уже в первой таблице  запись с текущим ИД.
И ваш пример не назвать большим объемом.

Comment: Мой пример это лишь информация за 6дней и таких списков несколько, около 5штук.

Comment: В mysql нет команды update or insert ?

Comment: @pincher1519, есть. Называется [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [MERGE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)) в SQL и ее аналога в  MySQL ([INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)). Как минимум это уже сократит ваши запросы к БД: проверка будет выполняться на стороне БД.

Второй вариант - писать все данные подряд во вспомогательную (временную) таблицу, не думая о дубликатах. Дубликаты отлавливать позже на стороне БД.

Третий вариант - обработать файл, подготовить массив, отфильтровав дубликаты, потом писать в БД.

Все сильно зависит от конкретных условий: частоты выполнения скрипта, размера файла.

**UPD.** [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) - для быстрого заливания данных в БД из текста (можно и без парсера обойтись в вашем случае - границы между полями и записями жестко заданы). Тогда алгоритм такой:

1. Залить данные во вспомогательную таблицу
2. При помощи [INSERT... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html) записать новые данные в основную таблицу (выбрать все записи, ID которых больше максимального в основной таблице)
3. Очистить вспомогательную таблицу

Comment: Раз в час. https://mmotop.ru/votes/3a8fdd1fe483004369f0638a0e909dbe0f38e53a.txt
пример файла. Файл обнуляется раз в месяц в первых числах, так что объем довольно большой выходит.

Comment: Id там вроде бы уникальный - читайте из базы последний id и потом пишите в базу все строки, у которых Id больше.

Comment: id разбросаны.

Comment: Интервалы между ID не важны. Важно, что у вас нет ситуаций, когда последующий ID меньше предыдущего - в примере, по крайней мере, так. Иными словами вы точно можете найти фрагмент, с которого данные нужно забирать.